# segregate list elements with different groups in java

Tags: java, list, arraylist

Suppose I have one list which always has the count of even number. Now I want to segregate the list with different group indexes with below conditions,

```
1) First element (1st element) with one index (EX: 1)
2) Next two elements with same index (Ex: 2nd, 3rd element with index 2,
                                          4th and 5th element with index 3)
3) Last element(6th element) with index 4
```

I tried with nested for loops to achieve the same, but didn't get the expected output.

Any help is appreciated.
Sample Input:

```
[2,3,53,52,33,12,44,66]
```

Sample Output:

```
2 - 1
3 - 2
53 - 2
52 - 3
33 - 3
12 - 4
44 - 4
66 - 5
```

Comment: The fact that you have code is a starting point.  Post your method here so that we can see what you have and where it went wrong.

Comment: It sounds like you are trying to categorize the elements in your list. If your list elements are always going to be unique, you could use a dictionary where the list elements are the keys and the dictionary values are the group/category numbers

Comment: @Vinod - I have added the answer, but don't know why negative vote for the working code, please check !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have implemented this using the two additional variables z and count, I am incrementing z only if the count%2 is 0, and at-last we need to check if the size-1 is equal to the i variable for the third condition.

Also, for the first condition I am printing the arraylist value at first index and z variable value at i if the i counter value is 0.

Please see the below code that I have simulated for your input list that I have added manually ! Please use the link to test :

http://rextester.com/ESYF23501

```
import javafx.collections.ArrayChangeListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<Integer> a= new ArrayList<Integer>();
        a.add(2);
        a.add(3);
        a.add(53);
        a.add(52);
        a.add(33);
        a.add(12);
        a.add(44);
        a.add(66);
        int i = 0;
        int z = 2;
        //Count to group the middle number by checking its value with respect to mod 2
        int count = 0;

        for (i = 0; i < a.size(); i++)
        {

            if (i == 0)
            {
                z = i+1;
                System.out.println(""+a.get(i)+" " + "" +z+"" );
            }

            if (i > 0 && i != (a.size() -1))
            {
                // Increment z if the count is even so that we print the group for two times
                if (count%2 == 0)
                {
                    z++;
                }

                System.out.println(""+a.get(i)+"" +" "+ ""+z+"" );
                count ++;
            }

            if (i == a.size() -1 )
            {
                z++;
                System.out.println(""+a.get(i)+"" +" "+ ""+z+"" );
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work correctly if I understood your question right:

```
System.out.println(elements.get(0) + " - 1");  // Prints the first number, which has the value of 1
int value = 2;  // Value corresponding to the number
for (int i = 1; i < elements.size(); i++) {  // Loops through the list starting at second element (index of 1)
    System.out.println(elements.get(i) + " - " + value);  // Prints the number and the value
    if (i % 2 == 0) value++;  // Increases the value every two loops
}
```

It starts by printing out the first number and 1, which as you described always corresponds to each other. Then it loops through the list of numbers starting at the second number (i = 1), and prints out each number and the corresponding value. The value increases every two loops, which is every time the loop number is divisible by 2 (i % 2).